# How to list properties of a Nestjs DTO class?

Tags: javascript, nestjs, prisma

I have following Nestjs DTO class:

```
// create-job-offer.dto.ts
import { IsOptional, IsNumber } from 'class-validator';

export class CreateJobOfferDto {
  @IsNumber()
  @IsOptional()
  mentorId: number;

  @IsNumber()
  @IsOptional()
  companyId: number;
}
```

I want to obtain the list of class properties: `['mentorId', 'companyId']`.

I tried so far in a controller without success following methods:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new CreateJobOfferDto());
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(CreateJobOfferDto);

Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(new CreateJobOfferDto());
Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(CreateJobOfferDto);

Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(CreateJobOfferDto);
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(new CreateJobOfferDto());

Object.getPrototypeOf(CreateJobOfferDto);
Object.getPrototypeOf(new CreateJobOfferDto());
```

If I add a method, or vars in a constructor, I can get them, but not the properties.

The reason why I want to achieve this is, I am using Prisma and React, and in my React app I want to receive the list of class properties so that I can generate a model form dynamically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no easy direct way to get the list of properties of a DTO class, or
more comprehensively, any type of class that has only properties.

The reason is that whenever you defined a property without any values, it becomes disappears after compiling to javascript.

**Example:**

```ts
// typescript
class A {
    private readonly property1: string;
    public readonly property2: boolean;
}
```

it compiles to this:

```js
// javascript
"use strict";
class A {}
```

In order to achieve this goal, you need to write a custom decorator. like this:

```js
const properties = Symbol('properties');

// This decorator will be called for each property, and it stores the property name in an object.
export const Property = () => {
  return (obj: any, propertyName: string) => {
    (obj[properties] || (obj[properties] = [])).push(propertyName);
  };
};

// This is a function to retrieve the list of properties for a class
export function getProperties(obj: any): [] {
  return obj.prototype[properties];
}
```

Imagine I have a DTO class for a user, like this:

```ts
import { getProperties } from './decorators/property.decorator';

export class UserDto {
  @Property()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  firstName: string;

  @Property()
  @IsEmail()
  @IsOptional()
  public readonly email: string;
}
```

and I want to get all properties in a list, so we need to call the `getProperties` method which we defined earlier, so:

```ts
import { UserDto } from './dtos/user.dto';

getProperties(UserDto); // [ 'firstName', 'email' ]
```

---

You can also use an npm module [ts-transformer-keys](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-transformer-keys).

> A TypeScript custom transformer which enables to obtain keys of given type.

**How to use:**

```ts
import { keys } from 'ts-transformer-keys';

interface Props {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
const keysOfProps = keys<Props>();

console.log(keysOfProps); // ['id', 'name', 'age']
```

Comment: great answer, thanks a lot. I'm surprise that when compiling TS to JS, it just deletes the keys, I'd would expect to initialise them as null or sth.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the custom solution Mostafa proposes, you can use the `@Expose` decorator combined with the `plainToInstance` function from the `class-transformer` library.

```
import { Expose } from 'class-transformer';

export class UserDto {
  @Expose()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  firstName: string;

  @Expose()
  @IsEmail()
  @IsOptional()
  public readonly email: string;
}
```

And to get the keys:

```
import { plainToInstance } from 'class-transformer';
import { UserDto } from './userDto';

const userDtoInstance = plainToInstance(UserDto, {});

console.log(Object.keys(userDtoInstance));
```